# Creating a custom flowchart block in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm searching for some tutorial or howto that explains how create custom Process Modeling Library (PML) blocks in AnyLogic 7.3.5.

I saw the slides used in a conference held in Philadelphia last 2015 November 4/5 that it is possible, as shown on [slide 7](http://www.anylogic.com/upload/conference/2015/presentations/alc2015-workshop.pdf). I know that a custom block is a **new AgentType** and **inside it I can create a "behaviour" using standard PML blocks**, I'm searching for a documentation that explains how are the steps to create a simple custom block to use it in my ''Main'' agent.

Thanks Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a tutorial but I do this quite often.
You have to create a new agent and the drawback of what I use is that it is associated to the project it is created on (unlike the custom ones which are always available...). I work around this importing the model where I have my custom Agent (=PML custom block)

Start by adding Ports (Palette>Agent) for the inputs and outputs and make sure they are part of the Icon and visible on the upper level. Then add the already existing blocks that compose the behavior you want. you can also add parameters and functions to have it be like an AL existing block...

Comment: Ok thanks. It is possibile to subdivide the new agent-type created in packages (in the project tab) like in java program I place my classes in packages to maintain them order logically?

Comment: @AndreaMeneghinello Each AnyLogic ALP file ('model') is a Java package; see the Java package name in the model properties. So, as jacandau says, you can keep your custom PML block in a separate ALP file (Java package). You have to have this 'model' open when you develop your 'real' model which uses it (and you can drag the custom blocks into your model as normal). This isn't really documented by AnyLogic AFAIK but is very powerful.